# Storing multiple references in one field

Tags: mysql

I need to store for each row of a table possible references to 5 other tables because I need to know, for each one of five tables, if are there references to the row .

I was thinking about using a "binary type" code so for each table I'll have a "0/1" and for five tables I'll have from "00000" (for no references) to "11111" (for five references).

So, if I only have references into table 3 I'll store "00100".

Now here are my questions:

1) Is it a good idea? Are there better solutions?

2) What kind of field do I need to use? (I was thinking ENUM)

**EDIT** (TO CLARIFY)

I need to know if I'll need to access (or not) to each of five table to get data related to the row.

The five tables are web tables so I need to know if I can find informations on a table or not.

**EDIT 2** (further clarification)

I don't query the web tables: I get info from them by code. The code reads from my DB to know how many web tables needs to access and which of the 5 existing.

Comment: Will you ever need to join this table to the other tables?  How will the reference be used (just need to know reference exists  (why wouldn't a left join work?)  Could the number of tables grow or shrink? Would you be better off using a xref table taking the PK out of the table and creating a record in a secondary table with the pk and table name?  In General, overloading a column in an RDBMS isn't wise.  What about "SET" data type if you MUST http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html

Comment: The question could use a little clarifying. The statements "each row of a table possible references to 5 other tables" and "each one of five tables, if are there references to the row" seem contradictory, or at best marginally related. Which references which? Why overcomplicate it with a bitfield when to actually reference you'll have to have a field to reference with.

Comment: @xQbert I edited the question (hope is more clear)

Comment: web tables? You mean `<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>` kind of tables? Furthermore: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Whether or not it's a good idea depends mainly on *why* you feel you need to do this. A **WHERE EXISTS** query would be slower, but orders or magnitude easier to maintain.

Comment: If those referencing tables have the referencing field(s) indexed, you're likely better off querying them directly compared to manually maintaining some bitfield. ...and assuming they are on the same server, you can even query multiple (all 1:1 relations and one 1:N) using `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: @Uueerdo I don't query the web tables: I get info from them by code. The code reads from my DB to know how many web tables needs to access and which of  the 5 existing.

Comment: So you mean like @Sumurai8 had asked/shown?

Comment: @Uueerdo Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I mean (for each table) "useful/unuseful"

Comment: @genespos How would you get information from database tables without querying?

Comment: @Uueerdo Ok, I try again to explain: my code query my db to know how to get info on the web. So first gets the number (and position) of tables of interest and then navigate to get info.

Comment: @RyanVincent Please have a look at my last comment (to Uueerdo)

Comment: Just for reference, if you are using mysql you have a binary type that allows that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-type.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would likely store the information in a Relational Database Management System relationally; as close to 3rd normal form or better as possible.  This means I would have two tables.

One table lists the available options.  A second table lists all the options affiliated with that object which is accessing the 5 web tables.

The reason I would do it this way has to do with being able to expand the application.  If additional web tables become available, or if other objects over time need access to different web objects, this model would support growth both in number of web objects, and objects accessing the web objects without having to touch code.

Now, if that's GUARANTEED not to happen, then I could see storing the values in a single field where position matters; perhaps using a "SET" data type.  But given there are few guarantees I would likely not take this approach just because it's not scalable without code change and doesn't perform as well under volume.

To address your specific questions:

**1) Is it a good idea? Are there better solutions?**

Personally I find the idea poor in that it can not easily scale without code change; and I don't see how an ENUM can be stored in one field without using set data types. (The two work well together but I don't think I've seen ENUM without set when storing multiple values in one field) I prefer a more relational method.  However, if we know that it will never grow, then I find the approach reasonable.

**2) What kind of field do I need to use? (I was thinking ENUM)**

I would prefer SET Datatype. I think it would be easier to scale and is more Consistent.  I'm not sure how you would multi select the ENUM data type; without storing it relationally or using set data types.  If you're adding a new table to store the ENUM values then that's more or less the same as what I would recommend.

But my exposure and use to ENUM is limited in this context; so I may not have some experience which would make this a reasonable approach.

Comment: In my experience ENUM is generally something to be avoided in MySQL. Any addition of new enum values requires the entire table to be recreated (behind the scenes). Also, it's behavior can be a little strange because it is treated like a string, "but not". Especially convoluted if some of the enum values happen to be numeric; as it is not clear when comparing it to '1' whether it will be true for the first (second?) value in the list or a different one named '1'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that my code is very far from a good code but (at the moment) this is what I'm able to do. I don't think that SET is better than ENUM (in this case) because using SET it's possible to insert empty values and also multiple values (e.g. '' or  '00100, 00110'). In both these cases inserted value will be wrong! In any case you've been the one who answered me so I'll accept ;)